# The while loop does print out different questions, however, it completely ignores the IF statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

The while loop does print out different questions, however, it completely ignores the IF statements.

CODE:

```
import random
min = 1
max = 4


myDict = {1: "What is the name of the world's tallest tower?" ,
          2: "What is the best youtube channel ever?" ,
          3: "When did Queen Victoria die?" ,
          4: "What is the world's most active volcano?"}


while True:
    question = print(myDict.get(random.randint(min, max)))
    answer = input("ANSWER: ")
 
    if question == myDict.get(1):
        if answer == "Burg Khalifa":
            print('Correct!')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
            continue
        continue
        
    if question == myDict.get(2):
        if answer == "Vat19" :
            print('Correct!')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
            continue
        continue
        
    if question == myDict.get(3):
        if answer == "1901" :
            print('Correct!')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
            continue
        continue
       
    if question == myDict.get(4):
        if answer == 'Mount Kilauea':
            print('correct!')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
            continue
        continue
```

Comment: Why two `continue` statements per `if`?  The one in `else` is redundant.

Comment: `print` returns None. So `question` is always None. You should set `question` equal to the question.

Comment: [How  to debug small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: As @khelwood mentions, the problem line is: `question = print(myDict.get(random.randint(min, max)))`
because you are comparing a print output (None) to a string.

Comment: Strongly recommend renaming the `min` and `max` variables, as these are currently overwriting the built-in functions.

Comment: Suggestion for cleaner code: instead of saving the whole question to `question`, save the random index generated, then save the answers in a list as well with matching indexes as the questions, and your `while` loop could have just one `if` condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that variable `question` isn't getting assigned as you expect, but rather assigned the return value of `print()`, (i.e. `None`). You need to split it as below -

```
question = myDict.get(random.randint(min, max))
print(question)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must delete the `print()` and take the `question` variable as a parameter of `input()` like this:

```
while True:
    question = myDict.get(random.randint(min, max))
    answer = input(question)
```

The `input()` method will print the question an get user input